# #Error in table(StudentSurvey$Gender, StudentSurvey$Smoke): object 'StudentSurvey' not found

Tags: r

So, I'm attempting to knit a R document to a HTML file however, when it knits it produces this error "#Error in table(StudentSurvey$Gender, StudentSurvey$Smoke): object 'StudentSurvey' not found"

For reference this is my R code.

```
read.csv("StudentSurvey.csv")
barplot(table(StudentSurvey$Gender, StudentSurvey$Smoke), legend=TRUE)
boxplot(StudentSurvey$Pulse ~ StudentSurvey$Smoke , xlab = "Smoke" , ylab = "Pulse")
```

I'm unsure whats wrong, I've tried to troubleshoot by changing my Rworking directory and ensure that "StudentSurvey.csv" is in there, but alas this issue appears to be happening. If it isn't immediately apparent I'm extremely new to R as I'm using it for the first time in UNI so apologies if this is a simple fix.

Comment: You need to save the output of `read.csv` in a variable. Try `StudentSurvey <- read.csv("StudentSurvey.csv")`

Comment: `StudentSurvey <- read.csv("StudentSurvey.csv")`.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to assign the output of read.csv() to an object.

```r
StudentSurvey <- read.csv("StudentSurvey.csv")
```